# Couldn't get the push notification using urban Airship in android

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have created an application in Google console, and get the GCM server API key. 
I have followed this link of Urban Airship to configure the App for Pushnotification. https://docs.urbanairship.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1509252

I have requested the Urban Airship and got the access to use GCM in my app, and created the Application in Urban Airship. I downloaded the sample application from Urban Airship and changed the package name to, which I have given in the Urban Airship application. 
I run that application in my Toshiba tab, having Android 4.0.3 OS. 
I got the AppId from the sample code. When I tried to send a test push from Urban Airship application, I didn't get the notification. Even didn't get any error. I implemented this for iphone also, inserted the certificate. I got pushes for iphone. I can see the device token in the app in Urban Airship. But I see in the AppId column, says like "You don't have any registered AppId". what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things that would be helpful in looking at the matter. First, do you have logcat output showing successful registration to Urban Airship, with a 200 response?

Also, sometimes the web console can take a bit of time to refresh itself after API registration, if your APID is still not showing as registered in the web console, I would suggest emailing `support@urbanairship.com`, they can look at your app key and better assist you from there.